# /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

Can't get plutus-playground-server to start.

plutus-playground-server: for development use only
/nix/store/601kdlvidgan842yfklrmvpbz6a5xkf7-plutus-playground-server/bin/plutus-playground-server: line 10: /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory

git version: 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a

Comment: Having the same issue and not sure what the problem is! Maybe an issue with latest in the HEAD of plutus-apps repo? Not sure! The dev experience so far is absolutely terrible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this that you can read in the document I wrote to setup Plutus dev environment on your local machine ( https://www.punkbit.com/hacking/plutus-developer-environment-setup-on-macos-monterey/#6-run-the-plutus-playground-service-and-frontend).

The issue is related to a segmentation fault and by disabling the garbage-collector when running the generated commands in the generated source files, solved it for me!

Here's part of the original generated script:

```
$(nix-build --quiet --no-build-output ../default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-playground-server.components.exes.plutus-playground-server)/bin/plutus-playground-server psgenerator generated
```

See the --quiet --no-build-output? That's bad! Remove it and you'll see the original error.

```
$(nix-build ../default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-playground-server.components.exes.plutus-playground-server)/bin/plutus-playground-server psgenerator generated
```

You should see a segmentation fault.

Prefix the command with GC_DONT_GC=1

Check the article I posted above, its easier.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooted my mac and it worked. I'm on macOS Monterey

[image]