# Plutus Playground Server error: opening lock file '/nix/...root.lock': Permission denied

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, nix, nix-shell, ubuntu

So I've been going through the Plutus Pioneers 3rd cohort lectures and last night accidentally left my computer unplugged. When I booted up Ubuntu Linux on the computer this morning I noticed I have 3 copies of plutus-apps folders on my computer and I only use one for going in nix-shell and running plutus playground so I deleted the other 2.

I went to set up Plutus-Playground-Server for a new lecture and went through the steps here to get everything set back up again (which have worked fine before since I've set it all up already).

https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Plutus/Build/Ubuntu/

In terminal window 1

```
cd plutus-apps
nix-shell
cd plutus-playground-server
plutus-playground-server
```

However, I am getting these errors (tried sudo plutus-playground-server as well, didn't work).

[image]

I thought maybe there's something that needs updating so I updated all my apps. I noticed my Nix is running on 2.8.1 and now there is 2.10

https://nixos.org/download.html

Tried several ways of updating nix including the methods given in the link, I keep getting these similar permission denied messages. Sudo doesn't work in this instance.

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client]$ GC_DONT_GC=1 plutus-playground-server
plutus-playground-server: for development use only
error: opening lock file '/nix/store/69h1ik7v55mi947xfn28bwxkvn2fn4z9-plutus-apps-root-plutus-ledger-constraints-lib-plutus-ledger-constraints-root.lock': Permission denied
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
error: opening lock file '/nix/store/69h1ik7v55mi947xfn28bwxkvn2fn4z9-plutus-apps-root-plutus-ledger-constraints-lib-plutus-ledger-constraints-root.lock': Permission denied
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
/nix/store/fm77y43lzpgnay4pyc48jwpln0lnmrk3-plutus-playground-server/bin/plutus-playground-server: line 10: /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory
```

Just to try everything I tried changing git versions of plutus-apps like you need to do as you go through plutus cohort #3. I did git checkout for different weeks of the plutus pioneer program and i'm getting:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree
```

[image]

However, the git checkout in plutus-community docs works just fine (but plutus playground server still doesn't work).

https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Guides/BuildCabalBuild/

I have restarted my computer as per this link, still getting the same errors.

[/bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/bin-plutus-playground-server-no-such-file-or-directory)

Is this having to do with the new cardano node 1.35.3 and the Vasil upgrade or just a bonehead move on my part? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue yesterday on Mac. GC_DONT_GC=1 did the trick for me.  Maybe restarting `nix-daemon` will work: `sudo pkill nix-daemon` & `sudo nix-daemon &`

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm on Ubuntu. I don't think that'll make much of a difference with Mac. 

/ When I did ```sudo pkill nix-daemon``` & ```sudo nix-daemon &```

/ went into nix-shell in plutus-apps 

/ changed directory to plutus-playground-client 

/ and ran ```plutus-playground-server```

I have only one error ```error: opening lock file '/nix/store/69h1ik7v55mi947xfn28bwxkvn2fn4z9-plutus-apps-root-plutus-ledger-constraints-lib-plutus-ledger-constraints-root.lock': Permission denied (use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)```

Comment: whereas before I would get the error twice. ```GC_DONT_GC=1 plutus-playground-server``` gives same error 2 times just like before, it's not working for me. 

-----

Now the next thing I need to figure out is how to enter new lines in comments on stack exchange comments so my replies can look cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

Went back and tried getting it to work today, first went to this link
https://www.punkbit.com/hacking/plutus-developer-environment-setup-on-macos-monterey/#6-run-the-plutus-playground-service-and-frontend

and added in my nix.conf file

`build-users-group = nixbld`

the playground server still wasn't working so I found someone having a similar github issue with Nix here

https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/4356

`sudo chown -R "Your User Account Name":staff /nix`

afterwards `plutus-playground-server` worked, no extra GC_DONT_GC=1 needed in my case.

This makes sense because I was getting logged permission errors from nix and this command gives me ownership of nix folder and subdirectories.

2nd terminal with

```
cd plutus-apps
nix-shell
cd plutus-playground-client
npm run start
```

is working fine, the plutus playground server is running for me.